# Cannot select SVG foreignObject element in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working with a d3 force-directed layout with HTML node labels implemented with SVG `foreignObject` elements.  I'd like to select these elements at various times to update their positions and other properties (and track them as they are created and destoryed with `enter()` and `exit()` ), but I don't seem to be able to select them like other SVG elements.

Here is a compact example:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cannot Select SVG Foreign Object</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
        <script src = "fo_select.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <svg id="example_svg" width="600" height="600">
               <g>
                  <circle r="40" cx = "80" cy="80"></circle>
                  <foreignObject width = "100" height = "100" x = "200" y="200">
                         <body>Hello, world</body>
                  </foreignObject>
               </g>
         </svg>
         <script>run()</script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function run() {
    svg = d3.select("#example_svg");
    console.log(svg.selectAll("circle"));
    console.log(svg.selectAll("foreignObject"));
}
```

This is also up at http://bl.ocks.org/3217448 .  The console output is:

```
[Array[1]]
[Array[0]]
```

where the first array contains the `circle` element, while the second one is empty.  Why is the `circle` object selectable, but the `foreignObject` is not?  I assume it has to do with the unusual nature of the `foreignObject`. How would I select it to manipulate it in my code? Thanks very much.

Comment: (Updated to remove extra comma typo)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strictly speaking, SVG is case sensitive so you should use `<foreignObject>` instead of `<foreignobject>`.

More seriously though, is that there's an open [bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438) that prevents camelCase elements from being selected.

One possible workaround is to use:

```
.selectAll(function() { return this.getElementsByTagName("foreignObject"); })
```

(This may not work in older WebKit versions though; see the now-closed [WebKit bug 46800](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46800).)

Alternatively, you can use CSS classes or IDs and select your elements that way instead. I would recommend this approach at the moment if possible, given the various aforementioned bugs.

Comment: Thanks very much - knowing that it's a bug makes me feel better. :-)  I'll just use class selection as a workaround.

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: '[object NodeList]' is not a valid selector." when using d3.selectAll(document.getElementsByTagName("foreignObject")). But selecting by the class name works perfectly. Thanks. It still seems to be a bug in Chrome 31.

Comment: Actually, there was a bug in my suggested workaround. I've updated it to use a function which is called for every element of the selection. My original suggestion only worked for d3.selectAll, not selection.selectAll.

Comment: A patch for this was submitted a year ago. Don't hold your breath on getting it fixed in WebKit.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to d3.selectAll("foreignObject") or svg.selectAll("foreignObject"). It may be that extra comma in your foreignObject attributes (between x and y). I've only inserted foreignObject elements using D3, so perhaps there's something about embedding them like this that's different.