# D3 Word Wrap on Zoomable Treemap

Tags: d3.js, word-wrap, treemap

I am implementing the Zoomable Treemap in D3 (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/), however I have modified it so the leaf rects will go to URLs when clicked. It also adds an ellipsis if the title is too long.

I'd like to implement word wrapping on leaf rects instead but cannot get it to work. I wanted to add a set of tspans to the text but am struggling with the execution order too much to understand where to put it.

Code: https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap.htm

Data: https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap.json

I've researched that I either need tspans breaking it up or a div with the text inside but don't know how to do either. There are examples of text wrap for the regular D3 Treemap but I've found none for the Zoomable Treemap and the code is significantly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is probably to replace the SVG `text` elements with `div`s inside `foreignObject`. To do that, you would replace

```
g.append("text") //was text
 .attr("dy", ".75em")
 ...
```

with

```
g.append("foreignObject")
 .attr("dy", ".75em")
 ...
 .append("xhtml:div")
 ...
```

It might also be advisable to set the `width` and `height` attributes of the `foreignObject` (using code similar to what you're using to determine whether the text is too long) so that the text flows correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the text inserted in the div is correct, but it does not get displayed on the screen (blank gray squares). i experimented with some height and widths but nothing shows up

Comment: Have you tried setting the font attributes (color etc) explicitly? It's also possible that it appears behind the rectangles; in that case try setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: Yes, see https://secure.polisci.ohio-state.edu/faq/d3/zoomabletreemap_1.htm. Doesn't get highlighted in Chrome inspector

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to use namespace `xhtml` for the `div` and set the size and position attributes on the `foreignObject`, not the `div`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That has it appearing. It looks like I'll need to figure out how to have them adjust size post-transition as they are currently maintaining their pre-transition places. (see zoomabletreemap_1.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this. Let me know if you have a thought on the post-transition, otherwise I may submit another question.

Comment: Looks to me like the offsets of the `g` elements are wrong -- the `rect` elements are positioned correctly. Maybe do a `.call(rect)` on them?

Comment: Tried that already, plus the foreign function is a copy/paste of the rect function. Thought they may not be part of s2, so I tried more global calls (e.g. 'd3.selectAll("foreignObject").call(foreign)') but no such luck. The offsets are exact to what the boxes were pre-transition. So the call is not working in 'transition' (either not called, or called before the transition is done).

Comment: Aha! It was this webkit bug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742812/cannot-select-svg-foreignobject-element-in-d3). The D3 selections were not being applied to the foreign objects due to them being camel case elements. It was working in FF. Selecting by classname gets it to work in Chrome also